# php_curl not working, even after all the neccessary steps

Tags: windows, iis, php

I am trying to enable php_curl on my windows 2003 server, using IIS. It just won't work.

1. I made sure the extension is enabled/uncommented in php.ini - I did notice that there are more than one php.ini files, so I made sure they were all the same.
2. The extension_dir setting is pointing to c:\php\ext (without the slash)
3. I have copied 'ibeay32.dll' and 'ssleay32.dll' from "C:\PHP5\ext" to '%windows%\system32 folder'
4. I even tried copying php_curl.dll from c:\php\ext to the windows system32 folder, that didn't work either.
5. I did php-cgi.exe -v from the command prompt, and no errors came up.

I don't get the same error that some of the other windows users are getting, which says 'unable to load php curl' - I get an error saying "Fatal error: Call to undefined function: curl_init()"

I made a test page with phpInfo, which is here: http://www.mrahmanphoto.com/blog/test.php

Its obvious that none of the additional modules are loading. What gives?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181082/how-do-i-install-curl-on-windows

Comment: Does IIS need to be restarted after making changes to php.ini?

Comment: Please set `display_startup_errors` to `On`, it may give you additional info in your error.log

Comment: @Gianps: yes, there are a lot of questions on php_curl, but none of them solved my issues...including the one you pointed out..

Comment: @DigitalPrecision: yes, I even rebooted a few times..

Comment: @dev-null-dweller: did that - where would it display the errors?

Comment: either in IIS logs or windows event log, or you can specify your own log file with `error_log` in php.ini BTW, your `phpinfo()` still shows `display_startup_errors` set to off, are you 100% sure you are editing `C:\WINDOWS\php.ini` file and restarting IIS afterwards ?

Comment: @dev-null-dweller: I did, but then php wouldn't load at all - I put the error log file, but no file got written ... there are permissions on that folder as well... not sure what is going on...