# How to call a website service from PHP?

Tags: php, web-services, callback, file-get-contents, http-get

My problem is the following, I have an EmailReports.php on my server which I use to send mails like EmailReports.php?who=some@gmail.com&what=123456.pdf

I can NOT modify EmailReports.php since that belongs to a diferent project and it instantly sends an email and has been aproved by QA team and all that stuff.

Now, on a diferent LookReports.php I need to offer a service like "Send me the reports I reviewed" which manually can be easily executed as just calling EmailReports.php, the question is, how can I do it by PHP code? so it calls the other PHP automatically.

I have tried without success:

```
$stuff = http_get("http://...<the url here>");
```

and

```
$stuff =  file_get_contents("http://...<the url here>");
```

I was thinking on import the EmailReports.php but does not seem right since there is no functions, it automatically sends an email.

Or I could replicate EmailReports.php code but that is against the QA policy since extra tests would be needed.

Could you guide me a bit?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get any errors when using file_get_contents? What is returned in $stuff? That would be the proper way of calling a foreign URL from a PHP script?

Comment: `file_get_contents` should work for a simple GET call.

Comment: @AaronDougherty Thx for reply, No errors, and $stuff is empty.

Comment: I would suggest printing the URL to the command line from PHP (assuming the URL is dynamic), then using curl on the command line to see what kind if results you get with out PHP interference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a [Curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) request to retrieve information (xml/html/json/etc) from any website.

**What is CURL? (short answer)**

> PHP has a very powerful library of calls that are specifically designed to safely fetch data from remote sites. It's called CURL.

Source : [PHP, CURL, and YOU!](http://blog.unitedheroes.net/curl/)

**Example of Curl function in PHP**

```
/* gets the data from a URL */
function get_data($url)
{
 if(function_exists('curl_init')){
 $ch = curl_init();
 $timeout = 5;
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
 $data = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 return $data;
 } else 'curl is not available, please install';
 }
```

Source : [Download a URL’s Content Using PHP cURL](http://davidwalsh.name/download-urls-content-php-curl)

> Alternatively, you could do what you are currently doing with `file_get_contents` but many hosts don't allow this. (Walsh, 2007)

**Usage**

```
<?php
$mydata = get_data('http://www.google.co.nz');
echo '<pre>';
print_r($mydata); //display the contents in $mydata as preformatted text
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Try to test it, with other websites because more often than not `google` will return a `404 request` (this is to be expected), after a curl has been executed.

Comment: This does not work neither, I think it could be server-configuration related?

Comment: Curl is now available by default with `PHP 5.4.3` [curl requirements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.requirements.php), alternatively if you're running something like a windows system with `xammp` installed I'd look into this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181082/how-do-i-install-curl-on-windows). Regards

Comment: I am using a remote Linux server with PHP 5.2.17, that may be the reason is not working, but I would expect an error at least.

Comment: On a windows system, you will need to uncomment the line in `php.ini` regarding `libcurl.dll`. (Alternatively read [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php) from php.org regarding installing curl on a windows enviroment). As stated above in a `linux` system (based on the version of php installed) no install should be required.

Comment: PHP 5.0.0 requires a libcurl version 7.10.5 or greater. (packages are available [here](http://curl.haxx.se/))

Comment: For previous versions of `PHP` refer to [this](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html) document from the [curl website](http://curl.haxx.se/) on installation for linux systems. Also use `phpinfo()` to check if curl is available. Regards