# how to use curl to incorporate this into my script?

Tags: php, curl

I have been advised to use this in my script

```
        curl -X POST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/HIDDEN/SMS/Messages.json \
        -u HIDDEN\
        -d "From=+442033228389" \
        -d "To=hidden" \
        -d 'Body=test'
```

But a simple cut and paste does not do the trick? How would I go about incorporating this into my script?

Results:

var_dump($output); 
 returns: bool(false)

var_dump($info);
 returns:

> array(26) { ["url"]=> string(95)
>   "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC7ae43150d51cce16de4be6ed0be5ca90/SMS/Messages.json"
>   ["content_type"]=> NULL ["http_code"]=> int(0) ["header_size"]=>
>   int(0) ["request_size"]=> int(0) ["filetime"]=> int(-1)
>   ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) ["redirect_count"]=> int(0)
>   ["total_time"]=> float(0.093) ["namelookup_time"]=> float(0)
>   ["connect_time"]=> float(0.093) ["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0)
>   ["size_upload"]=> float(0) ["size_download"]=> float(0)
>   ["speed_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_upload"]=> float(0)
>   ["download_content_length"]=> float(-1) ["upload_content_length"]=>
>   float(-1) ["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0) ["redirect_time"]=>
>   float(0) ["redirect_url"]=> string(0) "" ["primary_ip"]=> string(15)
>   "174.129.254.101" ["certinfo"]=> array(0) { } ["primary_port"]=>
>   int(443) ["local_ip"]=> string(11) "192.168.0.2" ["local_port"]=>
>   int(28469) }

Comment: Did you look [at the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)?

Comment: Check out the answer I gave, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572696/how-to-call-a-website-service-from-php/11572742#11572742)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/HIDDEN/SMS/Messages.json");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$data = array(
    'From' => '+442033228389',
    'To' => 'hidden',
    'Body' => 'test'
);
/* // WHERE $username = your account username
   // Where $password = Your account password
*/
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I'm sending data to a web service not pulling data

Comment: Sending data follows the same path, you just change it to a *Post* for instance.  Look here for more details.  You will still be using the same library... I'm updating my answer with details.

Comment: That should do the trick based on your example, based on the input that the api requires you may just need to json_encode that array before you add it to the curl_setopt

Comment: Just ran the example you given me, updating the needed information but i still did not recieve my expected notification

Comment: When you run that example do you:
    var_dump($output);
    var_dump($info);

Comment: Looks like you are missing your authentication.  Edit your original question and remove your account URL items, so everyone doesn't see it.  Also you will need to add your auth items which I'll edit in the example above see comments.

Comment: $info just gives transaction information did the $output show you any data?  If your authentication was incorrect then it should still give you Authenticate errors.  If thats the case then you'll have to find out from Twillio what the error is or if they can help you, but beyond that my example and the example from @hek2mgl is perfectly valid, minus the fact that he doesn't have authentication both should work just fine.

Comment: Try changing your post data with what the previous @hek2mgl noted with: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "From=+442033228389\nTo=hidden\nBody=test");  
Beyond that I cannot really help much more as everything else is valid curl wise.

Comment: I tried as an attempt moving it over to my hosting account and your example works.. I was testing from xampp with perl and  curl installed and sucessfully configured.. It is a problem on my servers end, not from the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exec shell command from inside a PHP script you'll have to use one of the functions `exec`, `shell_exec`, `system` or `proc_open` or simply the backtick operator `

```
$output = `curl -X POST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/HIDDEN/SMS/Messages.json -u HIDDEN -d "From=+442033228389" -d "To=hidden" -d 'Body=test'`;
```

But if you want to use curls functionality with PHP the better way would be to use the curl extension. Here comes an example:

```
<?php

// check if the curl extension is available
if(!function_exists('curl_init')) {
    die('the curl extension is not installed');
}

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/HIDDEN/SMS/Messages.json');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "From=+442033228389\nTo=hidden\nBody=test");

$result = curl_exec($ch);

// json_decode is used to translate the result into an object
var_dump(json_decode($result));
```

Comment: Your example returns null on the vardump

Comment: Completely different from mine, any ideas?

Comment: I would trace the traffic using wireshark