# cURL installed on Windows... but how to get it to work with PHP code?

Tags: php, windows, curl

**Background:**

I'm trying to get tweets from a specified username using PHP and OAuth. [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12939923/1708082) seems very useful. My problem is that my code doesn't return from the `$feed = curl_init();` line near the bottom. There are no errors displayed, I only know that it stops because my debug statements after that line are not executed.

I didn't have cURL installed so I installed it on my Windows machine (using [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17074237/1708082)). It still doesn't produce any errors, it just leaves and never comes back.

**Question:**

How do I access cURL from my PHP program where I want to use it?

Comment: full explanation here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: @Jessicat Did you find a solution? Im in the same situation right now.

Comment: @Ricardo I had to use Xampp as a server instead of using plain old Apache. Xampp seems to have it built in. It was way less of a fight.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the windows php zipped manual installer from windows.php.net, the manual zip comes with all the extensions. Once php has been installed, enable the CURL extensions.. and any other extension that you need in the php.ini file. Copy the php-production.ini to %systemroot% directory and rename it to php.ini.

Hope that helps !!!