# 'CURL' is not recognized as an internal or external command?

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

I am trying to query using `CURL` command in `ElasticSearch` in windows platform.

Ex: `localhost:9200/playground/equipment/1?pretty`

I am getting an error saying `CURL is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Please help me understanding the issue.

Comment: have you installed curl?

Comment: cURL is not installed on Windows by default. See previous Q/A for how to install cURL on Windows. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181082/how-do-i-install-curl-on-windows/17074237#17074237

Comment: better you use any REST client tools..its easy to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have already installed `curl`, add the directory where it's installed to the windows path:

Windows Vista and Windows 7 users

1 - From the Desktop, right-click **My Computer** and click **Properties**.
2 - Click **Advanced System Settings** link in the left column.
3 - In the System Properties window click the **Environment Variables** button.
4 - Select **Path** and click **Edit**.
5 - Append **;c:\path to curl directory** at the end.
5 - Click **OK**.
6 - **Close** and **re-open** the **command prompt**

[image: How to set the path and environment variables in Windows]

http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using cURL on windows for elasticsearch.

You should definitely better use any REST tool like [Post MAN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm) or [REST Console](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-console/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn).
If you want autocompletion, you should use [Marvel](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/marvel/).