# Running cURL on 64 bit Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, curl

I'm new to cURL, just got it installed but it seems to only do what it feels like.  I'm using the 64 bit version I got from here: http://curl.haxx.se/latest.cgi?curl=win64-ssl-sspi with installation instructions I found here: http://guides.instructure.com/m/4214/l/83393-how-do-i-install-and-use-curl-on-a-windows-machine.  Opening a new Powershell window I'm able to use a simple GET request like so:

```
curl http://localhost:3000
```

but if I run a POST

```
curl -d "hello world" http://localhost:3000
```

it tells me "Invoke-WebRequest : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'd' is ambiguous. Possible matches include: -DisableKeepAlive -Debug."

Trying to get help I type

```
curl -h or curl --help
```

gives me "Invoke-WebRequest : Missing an argument for parameter 'Headers'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.Collections.IDictionary' and try again."

As I mentioned, I'm a cURL newbie but it seems strange that it can do get requests but nothing else.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Windows 7 64 bit
Powershell version 4

Comment: Have you installed the certificate? I had a similar problem with curl and that fixed it for me.

Comment: Hey Ella, appreciate the feedback.  I did install the certificate but Windows has some other quirks I wasn't aware of that caused the problem (imagine that.)  JPBlanc had some info that got it working for me.

Answer (score 363, accepted):

Your problem is that your are not using the `Curl` you installed but a CmdLet called `Invoke-WebRequest`.

Just execute :

```
Remove-item alias:curl
```

And test your curl again, then store it in your profile.

The explanation is that it exists a native alias to the `Invoke-WebRequest` which is a CmdLet that is supposed to deliver a *kind of* curl service.

---

From Windows 10 build 17063 and later (April 2018), `Curl` is included into Windows, so that you can execute it directly from Cmd.exe or PowerShell.exe. To use it in PowerShell be careful to unalias this CmdLet or explicitly call curl.exe.

Built with Schannel (Microsoft's native TLS engine), libcurl still perform peer certificate verification, but instead of using a CA cert bundle, it uses the certificates that are built into the OS.

Comment: That Remove-item command worked perfectly.  Just ran it and now cURL is doing what I'd expected it to.

Comment: Where do you run this? Remove-item alias:curl

Comment: I ran it in the command prompt where I was running curl. It didn't return anything, but curl worked after running it

Comment: You can also run executable as god intended: `curl.exe`

Comment: @GaryCarlyleCook - it also runs fine in the integrated terminal of VSCode.

Comment: I need to use this command every time. How do I solve that?

Comment: You can put this command in your profile.

Comment: How to save it in the profile?

Comment: For example inside de file pointed by : `$profile.AllUsersAllHosts`

Comment: So I am just supposed to paste the exact command in the file?

Comment: It's 2022 and this is still an issue.

Comment: It's 2023 and this is still an issue.

Answer (score 5):

You can execute curl commands with **Command Prompt** instead of **Windows Powershell**. Command prompt doesn't alias curl commands like Windows Powershell does.

To open command prompt, hit `Win + R`, type `cmd` in the input box, `<Enter>`.

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr**

**Use `curl.exe` rather than `curl`** in order to predictably<sup>[1]</sup> target the [curl](https://curl.se/) executable (`C:\Windows\system32\curl.exe` ) that comes with recent versions of Windows; doing so works in both PowerShell editions:

```
# Note the ".exe" part
curl.exe -d 'hello world' http://localhost:3000
```

---

To elaborate on [JPBlanc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25045154/45375) and provide an alternative solution:

- In ***Windows PowerShell*, `curl`** does *not* refer to the external `curl.exe` *program*; instead, it **is a built-in [alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Aliases) for PowerShell's [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) cmdlet**.
- This **alias was removed in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**, where `curl` now *does* refer to `curl.exe` by default.

  - Other aliases were removed too, in a general attempt not to shadow external programs that come with the operating system any longer, though  note that this logic is applied on a per-platform basis (e.g., `ls` is *not* an alias *on Unix*-like platforms, so as not to shadow the native `/bin/ls` utility, but still is an alias of `Get-ChildItem` *on Windows*).
- When in doubt, pass a name to [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command) to see what command form it refers to (external executable, alias, cmdlet, function, or script).

While *manually* removing the alias in Windows PowerShell is one option, it affects the *whole session*, which may cause scripts (written for Windows PowerShell only) that rely on this alias to fail.

Therefore, the better, per-call solution is to use **`curl.exe`** in calls, i.e. to *include the filename extension*, `.exe`, as shown at the top.

---

<sup>[1] As with invoking any executable specified by *name only*, it is located via the (first) directory listed int the `$env:PATH` environment variable that contains an executable by that name. By default, `C:\Windows\system32\curl.exe` should be found, but it's possible to modify `$env:PATH` so that a version in a different directory is executed (but not one located in the *current* directory - the latter applies to `cmd.exe` only); for full robustness, use `& $env:windir\System32\curl.exe`.</sup>