# Problem with POST in cURL. Don't find the -X

Tags: curl, post

When I make the call, it says me this:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8000

Invoke-WebRequest : No se encuentra ningún parámetro que coincida con el nombre del parámetro 'X'.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 6
+ curl -X PUT http://localhost:8000
```

The get works well.

```
StatusCode        : 200
Content           : Recibió un método GET
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Connection: keep-alive
....
```

Thanks by the help.

Comment: Take a look at this answer to a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27719275/curl-in-power-shell-windows-8-1-a-drive-with-the-name-localhost-does-not-exi