# Laravel installation sail problem ((23) Failed writing body)

Tags: laravel, docker

I try to install laravel with the original laravel document but nothing happened, I got many errors, for example I tried this [command](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation#getting-started-on-windows) on **CMD**;

```
curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash
```

but I got this error

> (23) Failed writing body

When I tried with **PowerShell** I got this error;

```
cmdlet Invoke-WebRequest at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Uri:
curl : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'https' does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
 curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (https:String) [Invoke-WebRequest], DriveNotFoundException
 FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Specs;

> Docker Engine v20.10.0
>
> Edition   Windows 10 Home Version 20H2 Installed on   ‎14/‎08/‎2020 OS
> build 19042.685 Experience    Windows Feature Experience Pack
> 120.2212.551.0

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I ran into this issue as well and found the (usually excellent) Laravel documentation to be a little vague.

First of all, I have some knowledge of Docker but wanted to get much better acquainted so the recent release of Laravel Sail seemed like an excellent starting point.

1. Install Docker Desktop https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/
2. Install and enable WSL2 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10#simplified-installation-for-windows-insiders
3. The Laravel docs mention this in above step but the part I missed was installing a Linux distribution at the same time (via the Microsoft Store). I assumed Sail took care of this part.
4. Goto the windows store a get your distro e.g. Ubuntu 20.04 (https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/p/ubuntu-2004-lts/9n6svws3rx71?rtc=1)
5. Install Windows Terminal - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701?rtc=1&activetab=pivot:overviewtab. Up until now, I was using Cmder or ConEmu rather than the Command Prompt. The important difference is you can start a new shell for windows or any **of the Linux distributions you have installed**. Again, I assumed you could use the `curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash` command in my windows Cmder - not the case.
6. Start up a new Linux shell and if you `ls` you'll see your Windows filesystem. From there I `cd`'d to my projects directory, ran `curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash` and that took care of the rest.

One caveat is that you may have to enable any downloaded Linux distributions in Docker:

[image: Enabling WSL2 in docker for Linux distributions]

Of course, the process makes sense when you solve it and Sail does offer some useful shortcuts in getting a Laravel project up and running quickly with Docker but complete newcomers could be forgiven for thinking it takes care of absolutely everything - which it doesn't.

**Side note**

The reason you were getting the error in PowerShell is because PS has an alias for `curl` but not the curl you expect. ([cURL in power shell windows 8.1: "A drive with the name 'localhost' does not exist"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27719275/curl-in-power-shell-windows-8-1-a-drive-with-the-name-localhost-does-not-exi))

You can permanently remove this (https://github.com/lukesampson/scoop/issues/56#issuecomment-609098474) but you may not need to now you know how to use the command in your Linux shell.

Comment: I typed the command curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash but nothing happens. Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

The solution above provided by [@chris-j](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65320881/11352450) works like a charm, but if you still get the error "Docker in not running" even if the it's green consider doing the following

- Do `sudo su` and then `curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash`

Comment: Yes from my distro I get the same error

Comment: it's not worth it, specially on windows it was so slow, i switched to laragon easy to use and faster