# Laravel 8: docker pull access denied

Tags: laravel, docker, laravel-8

I'm trying to install Laravel 8 on my machine, but am running into an issue.
When I try to run the command `curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash` from the linux shell, i get the error:

```
Unable to find image 'and:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for and, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
See 'docker run --help'.

Get started with: cd example-app && ./vendor/bin/sail up
```

The directory remains empty, logically since it can't download anything.
I tried logging into docker but this generated the same error.
I've followed the accepted answer a fellow user listed in [Laravel installation sail problem ((23) Failed writing body)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65312815/laravel-installation-sail-problem-23-failed-writing-body) but this hasen't resolved the problem.

Do you have any idea on how to resolve this issue so i can go ahead with installing laravel?

Comment: what docker version you use? Also are you in windows or Linux or Mac ?

Comment: I'm using Docker version 20.10.2 running on  Windows 10 Pro (build 19042.746) with Ubuntu 20.04 for WSL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here are the spaces in the path of the folder where you are executing the command.

> Unable to find image 'and: latest' locally

You probably have a folder called *"X and Y"* and that's why it takes *"and: latest"*
One way to solve this problem is by removing spaces from the folder, which will solve other potential headaches in the future.

The other way is to copy all the code from https://laravel.build/example-app and put quotes around `"$(pwd):/opt"`

I know it is late for the answer but I hope to help someone else who is in the same situation.