# Enable CURL on Windows For PHP5.6.4

Tags: php, curl, hybridauth

Im trying to use [HybridAuth](https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth) in one of my projects, the error message im getting is

> Original error message: Hybridauth Library needs the CURL PHP extension.

Even though i have enabled cURL in my `php.ini`
    extension=php_curl.dll

here is a screenshot of my `phpinfo()`

[image]

What else i have to do in-order to enable the cURL extension, the related `php_curl.dll` is also present in the `ext` dir

Message that i get when i restart the apache server

> C:\Apache24\bin>httpd -k restart AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably
>   determine the server's fully qualified domain  name, using
>   fe80::a02e:1c05:c6ad:9332. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to
>   suppress this message

[image]

Comment: Are you using MAMP or something? Because it caches the php.ini file somewhere else rather than in original directory.

Comment: Restart the server and check

Comment: Clear your browsing history & cache and reload your server. You can visit http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/php/install.html and http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php for installation.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal i have separately installed the apache, php and mysql

Comment: @KirenSiva i have checked after restarting the apache server

Comment: @GauravDave nope same old error message... tried clearing the browser cache

Comment: @Johnx , try searching the phpinfo() page only , it might have some information on curl if it has been enabled.

Comment: When you restart, does it give any error/warning (like: apache is already running), else you could install xampp, will makes you're life easier.

Comment: @GauravDave nope, i'll update the message apache gives, but that is i think related to some domain name config...just a sec

Comment: @GauravDave plz check the edit in question

Comment: @Johnx , It should be related to your php configuration , see if your phpinfo contains something like this : http://i.imgur.com/RpfUji4.png

Comment: @Johnx Edit you're apache2.conf file and add ServerName localhost in that.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal I have added the curl part of my phpinfo to the question plz have a look i dont have anything like your config i.e a separate cURL section...

Comment: @GauravDave tnx added the servername and the warning went away, but the original problem still persists :(

Comment: Then it isn't yet added. Are you sure you have uncommented ( removed ; in front of ) php_curl.dll line? And on x64 machine? : have you seen this ques : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25044010/running-curl-on-64-bit-windows

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal plz have a look at last screenshot i have added in the question edit

Comment: Paste the Output of a sample curl request. Try the above link i have commented. And x86 or x64 version ? There are good answers here too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181082/how-do-i-install-curl-on-windows

Comment: eventually i end up downgrading my php version, thanks everybody for the support..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so it turns out i need a fixed version of curl which i could not find for PHP_5.6.4, so i downgraded to `PHP Version 5.4.3` and then downloaded **Fixed curl extension**(dont know what it is) from [here](http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/) replaced the original `php_curl.dll` with the one i downloaded and voila it worked.

The following SO post helped me fix the problem

[PHP cURL not working - WAMP on Windows 7 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939248/php-curl-not-working-wamp-on-windows-7-64-bit)

P.S please feel free to edit the answer as i dont know the exact reason why its working now and why it was not earlier...

Comment: there are no one know how to install curl with php5.6

Answer (score 10):

You have to add PHP install path to windows environment path. For example it you install php on `C:\PHP`, add both `C:\PHP` and `C:\PHP\ext` to windows path. Some how Apache cannot find curl dependencies libeay32.dll, ssleay32.dll and libssh2.dll

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if  (in_array  ('curl', get_loaded_extensions())) {
    echo "cURL is installed on this server";
}
else {
    echo "cURL is not installed on this server";
}
```

See, if that works.

Comment: `cURL is not installed on this server`

Answer (score 1):

get back the original `php_curl.dll` file ( from the zip file you downlaoded from php.net )

copy libssh2.dll, php_curl.dll, ssleay32.dll, libeay32.dll to Windows\system32 folder

this worked with me i have php 5.6.6 x64 ts with apache 2.4.10 in windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the PHP install path to the Windows environment path. For example, if you install PHP on `C:\PHP`, add both `C:\PHP` and `C:\PHP\ext` to the Windows path. Somehow, Apache cannot find curl dependencies `libeay32.dll`, `ssleay32.dll` and `libssh2.dll`.