# CURL installation not working on WAMP

Tags: php, curl, wamp

I was using WAMP version 2 which was running on Apache 2.2.17 and PHP 5.3.5. and I successfully installed `curl` and it worked fine. But I later installed WAMP version 3 running on Apache 2.4.18 and PHP 5.6.19. now I tried installing `curl` following the directions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14736235/5585069) and also  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27780610/5585069) but it's not working.

Please anyone has an idea of how to make it work?

Comment: you might need to re-install it

Comment: You dont install cURL all you need to do is activate it. `wampmanager->php->php extensions->php_curl` if there is no Tick beside the `php_curl` then click, it will be activated, and Apache will automatically restart

Comment: Latest version of WAMPServer is `3.0.9`. [Upgrade available here](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) along with updates for Apache/PHP/MySQL/MariaDB/phpMyAdmin/XDEBUG etc etc etc