# "Positional Parameter" error when posting data with cURL

Tags: php, curl, http-post

If I were to issue the command without the `--data "..."`, it works just fine. I've tried Google and I can't find any answers to this problem. Following the directions located [here](https://guides.instructure.com/m/4214/l/83393-how-do-i-install-and-use-curl-on-a-windows-machine) I'm getting the following errors when I attempt to post data with cURL:

```
PS C:\Users\David> curl --data "SMethod=0" "http://localhost/terra/modules/scripts/Query.php"
Invoke-WebRequest : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'SMethod=0'.
At line:1 char:1
+ curl --data "SMethod=0" "http://localhost/terra/modules/scripts/Query.php"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Your problem is answered here: [Running cURL on 64 bit Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25044010/running-curl-on-64-bit-windows)

You're not running curl you're running something called Invoke-WebRequest, which is aliased to curl.  You need to unalias curl, [download](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) and install curl (if you haven't already).

Answer (score 43):

`Remove-item alias:curl`

this will be happen to curl easily!!

TRY AND FUN.. AND ALSO `curl` can make your own
`SHORTEN URL` , so Don't need to work with 3rd parties.. :D

Answer (score 12):

Use the Command Prompt instead of using PowerShell.

If you are using PowerShell then you will need to prefix the curl command with `cmd /c`. For example:

```
cmd /c curl --data "SMethod=0" "http://localhost/terra/modules/scripts/Query.php"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: he means use cmd as opposed to PS

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers already mentioned the curl command in powershell is **aliased** and uses the [Invoke-WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) cmdlet under the hood. It has similar capabilities to curl.

**You can make a POST request and send & receive data without the need to install anything:**

```
curl -body "SMethod=0" "http://localhost/terra/modules/scripts/Query.php" -Method 'POST'
```

The option `-body` (Invoke-WebRequest) is the equivalent of `-d` or `--data` (curl). The [HTTP Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)) also must be specified.

This [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29200294/6710876) also considers [New-WebServiceProxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-webserviceproxy) and [Invoke-RestMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod).

Answer (score 0):

To resolve it, specify Git Bash or any other terminal type other than PowerShell in your VS Code Editor.

There is a drop down menu for terminal types to the right of the main terminal window. Should look something like this: + v (click the upside down carrot and select git bash).

If Git Bash isn't and option. Install Git Bash. Git Bash is wonderful.

To remove PowerShell curl alias, use this command:

```
Remove-item alias:curl
```