# translate Postman post Request with Basic Auth to mingw64 curl and powershell On Windows 10

Tags: powershell, curl, windows-10, postman, mingw-w64

I would like to translate a POST Request test from Postman to curl on Windows!

note: `ip`, `username`, `password` *are illustrative for this question!*

[image]

[image]

Consuming from Postman, I get `200 OK Code` fine!

But, Trying to use [curl](https://curl.se/windows/dl-7.74.0_2/curl-7.74.0_2-win64-mingw.zip) from cmd is not working!

Checking on Postman the `curl code`
[image]

I was trying on Powershell

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://10.31.7.52/BdN_SMS_CXP/api/SendSMS' --header 'Authorization: Basic bWFyaWVsYTpZMFMkaSRfViZTLjQwNio=' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{"ANI" : 3007209820}'

curl --location --request POST 'http://10.31.7.52/BdN_SMS_CXP/api/SendSMS' --header 'Authorization: Basic bWFyaWVsYTpZMFMkaSRfViZTLjQwNio=' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{\"ANI\" : 3007209820}'
```

checking codification/decodification is fine.

[image]

Now directly with user and password, according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/27442239/811293

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://10.31.7.52/BdN_SMS_CXP/api/SendSMS' --user 'mariela:Y0S$i$_V&S.406*' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{"ANI" : 3007209820}'
```

Here my results.
[image]

When I use `curl` of `mingw64` `7.71.1 version`,  the command is misinterpreted, because I get a `407 error`, `Authentication required`. It's not just a [powershell problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28128918/811293) solved with [Remove-item alias:curl](http://like%20https://stackoverflow.com/a/25045154/811293).

I suspect you should escape some characters, and use double commas `"` instead of single commas `'`.

**What considerations should I have with `$`, `_`, `&`, `.` and `*` characters (if I should have it with any)?**

**How should I write the request in powershell (or mingw64 curl) for it to work?**

Answer (score 0):

The generated command is not powershell curl but cmd curl :

you can just use it in cmd as it is,

[image]

or if you want to use powershel use it as:

[image]

```
$command= "curl --location --request POST 'http://10.31.7.52/BdN_SMS_CXP/api/SendSMS' --header 'Authorization: Basic bWFyaWVsYTpZMFMkaSRfViZTLjQwNio=' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{""ANI"" : 3007209820}'"

cmd /c $command
```