# Curl Upload-File inside Shell Runner

Tags: shell, curl, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to upload a single file via curl from within a gitlab-shell-runner.

Basically I need to use this command:

```
curl --user <user:password> --insecure --upload-file <file> https://example.com
```

Following error is shown:

```
 Invoke-WebRequest : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument "<user:password>"
```

Which adjustments do I need to make, to run this inside gitlab-ci?

I have already tried to use a variable for the address and different variation of quotations.

Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in "[Running cURL on 64 bit Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25044010/6309)" you are running a  `CmdLet` called `Invoke-WebRequest`, which has a `curl` alias in Powershell.
Start by removing it:

```
Remove-item alias:curl
```

Then check if your script does call the actual `curl` command (or you might need to [call it explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40105646/6309)).

Or: use [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Invoke-WebRequest?view=powershell-5.1) (aliased '`curl`') with a [`Basic $encodedCredentials` header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52784956/6309).