# store Result of curl + jq into a Variable usable in powershell (used in AZURE Pipeline script)

Tags: powershell, variables, curl, jq

I have Curl + jq sentence that works well in command line :
**C:\WINDOWS\system32>curl -k -u user:password -Ss http://10.0.0.2:5252/xxx | jq -r ".list|.items" | jq ".[]|select(.text=="RL/for_01.01.00")"| jq -r ".number"
01.01.00**
it return this 01.01.00 value
I need to have it into a Variable to reuse it late into my pipeline. but impossible to make it.

I tried this with no success :

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
  targetType: 'inline'
  script: |
  Write-Host "Retrieve the Version# from Branch name"
  $version=$(echo $(curl -k -u user:password -Ss http://10.0.0.2:5252/xxx | jq -r '.list|.items'| jq ".[]|select(.text=="$(Build.SourceBranchName)")" | jq -r '.number'))
  Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=version]$version"

it alway return this
At E:\azureDevOpsAgents_work_temp\a0a21d4a-f6e6-4526-8711-d42b8a06a5f1.ps1:4 char:34

- $version=$(echo $(curl -k -u ***:*** -Ss http://10 ...
- ```
                          ~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameter,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

It seem to do not acces at all this syntaxe
Ha some one an Idea of the wau to put my cURL + JQ filtering result into a variable ?

Comment: Depending on your version of PowerShell, ```curl``` is an alias for ```Invoke-WebRequest```, which is what is actually being called in your code - try ```curl.exe``` instead to disambiguate between the alias and the external application. See here for more details... https://stackoverflow.com/a/76591260/3156906

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: In short: In _Windows PowerShell_ (but no longer in _PowerShell (Core) 7+_) `curl` is  built-in alias of `Invoke-WebRequest`, whose syntax is very different from that of `curl.exe`. To reliably invoke the latter (on Windows), invoke it _with `.exe`_ (`curl.exe ...`)

Comment: Thanks, I Add the .exe and it works. 
I was initially thinking it was my Syntax that was wrong (the $(echo $(... )and not the "curl" call itself. thanks to have answered me even if there was existing topics on the curl vs curl.exe.