# PusherException: There is missing dependant extensions - please ensure both cURL and JSON modules are installed

Tags: javascript, php, pusher

I am newbie in pusher. I just integrated pusher in code igniter and i got pusher exception.

```
 PusherException: There is missing dependant extensions - please ensure both cURL and JSON modules are installed
```

How can i solve this. I can't get any idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception provides everything you need to know:

> please ensure both cURL and JSON modules are installed

cURL and JSON are PHP modules that need to be installed in your PHP environment as they Pusher PHP library depends on these to function.

If you could provide more information about your PHP runtime (PHP version and operating system) it may be possible to help you install these.

How to install cURL on Windows can be found here: [How do I install cURL on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181082/how-do-i-install-curl-on-windows)

Official docs on the installation of cURL can be found here:
http://php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php

Installing the JSON module for PHP5:
http://slaptijack.com/system-administration/lets-install-json-for-php-5/

Official docs here:
http://php.net/manual/en/json.installation.php

Generic information on installing PHP on Windows can be found here:
http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php

Comment: PHP version is 5.4.12 and is windows 8.1 . How to install it. Please guide me.