# PHP cURL not working on Windows x64

Tags: php, curl, xampp

So I have been trying  to find out somewhere something about this topic and with no luck among all tutorials and help forums and even on stackoverflow was I able to find something that could resolve my issue.

As the tittle states, I am running **XAMPP** on my **Windows 8.1 x64** machine, and when trying to open a very simple php page with curl stuff in it, it just wont DO anything or SHOW anything.

Tried enabling the displaying of errors, no help. (PHP and cURL)

**Yes** it is enabled in the one and only **php.ini** file I have

But when I transfer the same file to a Linux server it works normally.

If anyone could help me I would really appreciate it.

Comment: is the curl actually outputting anything?

Comment: This answer might help you find the real culprit http://stackoverflow.com/a/181555/587811

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Nope. Just a blank page and NO errors or anything.

Comment: @MoshMage The one that is upvoted the most is not available anymore. And the one that is marked is not helping also

Comment: I meant is the code actually programmed to output anything. have you tried a simple `<?php echo "hello world!"; ?>` script?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Yes it is. it should output some JSON stuff. As I said it is working when I trnsfer the file to a Linux server but on my home PC it's not working.

Comment: so you're actually meaning that your xampp installation will not output anything from any script? we're getting closer. I'd either [reinstall](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/xampp.htm) all this or go through configuration tutorials to make sure everything is alright. then, try a simple hello world script to make sure your server is actually working. then, try your cURL script.