# PHP/ASP.NET MVC Web-Api Somebody Know How To Use PHP To Call WEBAPI With POST

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, apache, asp.net-web-api

Please help me to tell me how to use the PHP to call asp.net web api ,thanks.
sorry I didn't use PHP before , so I just want to use very simple code to call server side of the WebAPI .
Thank you for your patience if you have read my question to the end.

> PS: I have done this issue and sharing how to handle this as following

How do I install CURL on Windows?

this url could be dealed with my problem , I will try to do it .thanks all

**Steps**

> ```
> 1. to check your php.ini address ,   
> 2.Search or find the following : ‘;extension=php_curl.dll’   
> 3.Uncomment this by removing the semi-colon ‘;’ before it        
> 4.Save and Close PHP.ini    
> 5.Restart Apache
> ```

reference address for all
http://www.tomjepson.co.uk/enabling-curl-in-php-php-ini-wamp-xamp-ubuntu/

Comment: If you don't know PHP at all, then hire someone to do it. You atleast need php fundamentals to make an API call.

Comment: thanks Daan , I just want to show how to across platfrom between PHP and Web Api,

Comment: Not your fault willie. I think there are some folks that would rather downvote than simply answer a question. I am interested in the same thing as I am a C# developer that is now working on a php project. I don't know php but I have been developing software for 17 years. I don't need to be told to hire a php developer. As a response, that provides zero value. I just need someone with php experience to point me in the right direction. I thought that was the void sites like SO were supposed to fill. Yeah yeah, I know the question posting "rules."

Comment: Hi @chad ,thanks you for your feedback, I am totally agreement  with your comment, maybe next time we can help each other to deal with PHP problems, hopefully this is a good solutions too us .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How do I install cURL on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181082/how-do-i-install-curl-on-windows)

this url could be dealed with my problem , I will try to do it .thanks all

Steps

```
1.<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>  To check your php.ini address ,      
2.Search or find the following : ‘;extension=php_curl.dll’    
3.Uncomment this by removing the semi-colon ‘;’ before it    
4.Save and Close PHP.ini    
5.Restart Apache
```

reference address for all
http://www.tomjepson.co.uk/enabling-curl-in-php-php-ini-wamp-xamp-ubuntu/

Comment: Thanks All , next time I will follow your advance to comment,thanks again ,and good luck .

Comment: Did this solve your problem? @Readers: if it solved his problem then it's a reasonable answer.

Comment: Dear All , yes this solution can be deat with this question , Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Normally the call is made through curl extension ( I advise you to take some time to read about it ) . Here is a function I use to make curl  requests (in json):

```
function make_curl_request()
  {
          $data = []; // data to send 
          $data_string = json_encode($data);
          $ch = curl_init("http://localhost:8000/function");
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
              'Content-Type: application/json',
              'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
          );
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

          //execute post
          $result = curl_exec($ch);


          curl_close($ch);
          $result = json_decode($result,true);
          print_r($result);

  }
```

Comment: thanks thegentletrainer, but i've got "Call to undefined function curl_init()" , how can i deal with this problem,

Comment: you need to make sure that the curl extension is enabled in your server

Comment: create a php file with <?php echo phpinfo(); ?> inside it. call it in your browser and with ctrl+f search for "curl" .. and then see if it's enabled or not . I am sure it's not enabled ... and then you have to enabled ( just google it ) good luck

Comment: thankyou , but how to do , please help me to give my any resource to handle this issue ,thanks

Comment: Hi thegentletrainer,, you are right ,I didn't find it out in the browser ,I try to handle this problem , will you mind give me more information ,thanks

Comment: http://www.walkswithme.net/enable-curl-library-in-xampp-localhost   this mighit help you if you're using xampp . Otherwise , just google it . There are thousands of articles / tutorials

Answer (score 1):

You need to use curl for that:

```
$curl = curl_init('http://myapi.com/');
$post_data = array(
    'post_var_1' => 'foo',
    'post_var_1' => 'bar'
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
if ($curl_response === false) {
    // handle api call error here ...
} else {
    // get your results from $curl_response here
}
```

Comment: thanks vard , but i've got "Call to undefined function curl_init()" , how can i deal with this problem,

Comment: You probably don't have curl on your server then. Do you try it on your development server or on your production server?

Comment: I have tried it on my server, the feedback it "Call to undefined function curl_init()",thanks vard

Comment: Is this a dedicated server that you can administrate, or a shared hosting ? If it's a shared hosting you'll probably not be able to get curl. Could you check in your phpinfo if `pecl_http` is available ? It's an other php extension you could use to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: sorry sir , it isn't found on the browser with  "php echo phpinfo()"

Comment: All right. For your information, for doing a phpinfo you need to put this (without `echo`) in your phpinfo.php file : `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`