# Curl is not working on my live server

Tags: php, curl

I have using sms gateway api on my server

```
$live_url = "http://sms6.routesms.com:8000/bulksms/bulksms?username=XXX&password=XXX&type=1&dlr=0&destination=XXX&source=routesms&message=CurlSecond";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $live_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

For this,

if i do `var_dump(curl_exec($ch));`,  It is showing `false`

if i do `var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));`,  It is showing like

```
array(26) { ["url"]=> string(153) "http://sms6.routesms.com:8000/bulksms/bulksms?username=XXX&password=XXX&type=1&dlr=0&destination=XXX&source=routesms&message=CurlSecond" ["content_type"]=> NULL ["http_code"]=> int(0) ["header_size"]=> int(0) ["request_size"]=> int(0) ["filetime"]=> int(-1) ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) ["redirect_count"]=> int(0) ["total_time"]=> float(62.345893) ["namelookup_time"]=> float(0.08692) ["connect_time"]=> float(0) ["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0) ["size_upload"]=> float(0) ["size_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_upload"]=> float(0) ["download_content_length"]=> float(-1) ["upload_content_length"]=> float(-1) ["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0) ["redirect_time"]=> float(0) ["certinfo"]=> array(0) { } ["primary_ip"]=> string(0) "" ["primary_port"]=> int(0) ["local_ip"]=> string(0) "" ["local_port"]=> int(0) ["redirect_url"]=> string(0) "" }
```

What i have to do?

I can't understand the issue?

I have tried one more way, Instead of curl, i have used

```
file($live_url);
```

This is also not working

Comment: The first thing you should do is add error handling to your code. Take a look into the documentation, that _always_ is helpful: http://php.net/manual/de/function.curl-error.php

Answer (score -1):

Please cross check is curl is installed on your server, if curl is not installed try following.

If it is ubontu server RUN

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

Restart Your Server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Alternatively, if you are using php-fpm, you'll need to restart php5-fpm instead

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

Hope this works ...

Comment: Im using windows, How can i restart the curl

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181082/how-do-i-install-curl-on-windows

Comment: Here, Iam not using in local server. Using in live server. There, I cant find the curl

Comment: `var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));` would have given a completely different output if cURL wasn't installed.