# Windows php curl post file failed with empty return value

Tags: php, windows, curl, file-upload

```
httpPost("http://test.test",
   ["file" => "@test.doc", "type"=>"application/octet-stream"], []);
```

which `test.doc` can be found at the `getcwd()`.

this code with test.doc works well in linux, but get empty return value in windows 7

Comment: have you enable curl in windows ? check for `php.ini` also check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181082/how-do-i-install-curl-on-windows?rq=1

Comment: @Noman checked with curl_init and php_info