# Can't install Laravel (Windows)

Tags: php, windows, laravel, composer-php, installation

```
  C:\Users\User>composer global require "laravel/installer"
Changed current directory to C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/Composer
You are running Composer with SSL/TLS protection disabled.
Warning: Accessing packagist.org over http which is an insecure protocol.
Using version ^1.3 for laravel/installer
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Warning: Accessing packagist.org over http which is an insecure protocol.
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - guzzle/guzzle v3.9.3 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - guzzle/guzzle v3.9.2 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - guzzle/guzzle v3.9.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - guzzle/guzzle v3.9.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - guzzle/guzzle v3.8.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - guzzle/guzzle v3.8.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - rackspace/php-opencloud dev-master requires guzzle/guzzle ~3.8 -> satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.8.0, v3.8.1, v3.9.0, v3.9.1, v3.9.2, v3.9.3].
    - Installation request for rackspace/php-opencloud dev-master -> satisfiable by rackspace/php-opencloud[dev-master].
```

Can't install Laravel 5.4 on Windows, I am a beginer at beck-end, so I never worked with composer before, I install php and composer, unpack curl to the root directory, but I have an error.

Comment: Ask that in english please

Comment: Did you restart apache after curl installation?

Comment: you need to install curl as a PHP extension, usually editing the php.ini file

Comment: And what sould I write there?

Comment: Try this out for laravel development on windows: https://laragon.org/ - Laragon has an isolated environment with OS and offers everything you need to build modern web apps. It is portable and very flexible. You can move Laragon folder around (to another disks, to another laptops, sync to Cloud,...) and Laragon's magics are with you.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is awsome tool!

Comment: @VladislavLuchan You're welcome! The forums are a great place to troubleshoot any issues you have. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not php curl extension.

> ```
> [Install curl for windows][1]
> ```
>
> [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/):
>   [How do I install cURL on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181082/how-do-i-install-curl-on-windows)

And you should add question in russion language to stack overflow for russian. [Stack on russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)