# Member Directory:How to enable visitors to my webpage to search information of contacts in my infusionSoft CRM

Tags: php, api, search, infusionsoft

I want to build a member directory which enables visitors to search the member information (basically just the addresses and contact) I store in the InfusionSoft CRM. Can I use the InfusionSoft API to fetch data from the CRM and post the retrieved data to my website? I am new to php and web development. Any help are appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you can indeed use the InfusionSoft API for this. When I've worked with InfusionSoft and PHP I've found [this](https://github.com/novaksolutions/infusionsoft-php-sdk) library to be more useful than the one InfusionSoft themselves provide.

Comment: Is OAuth problem involved? I want to make this search function public which means visitors don't need to log in to search. Could u provide more details on how to start?

Comment: If you use a PHP script on your server to run the queries through the InfusionSoft API, your server will be the only one that requires an API key. You can allow users to run specific queries through requests sent to your own PHP scripts without authentication. I'll try and provide some code examples as an answer if I've got the time.

Comment: Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Follow the Installation Directions for Novak Solutions SDK found [here](https://github.com/novaksolutions/infusionsoft-php-sdk/wiki/Examples). There are lots of good code samples on here too though you want to checkout.

Mainly these two things are important.

> Copy the Infusionsoft directory to your project.
>
> Copy the config.sample.php file to config.php and put in your Infusionsoft app hostname and api key.

```
    <?php


require_once('Infusionsoft/infusionsoft.php');


$contacts = Infusionsoft_DataService::query(new Infusionsoft_Contact(), array('Email' => 'POSTREQUEST HERE'));

foreach($contacts as $contact) {
    // Return these
}
```

Comment: I tried to run the sample codes provided by the sdk on easyPHP, but it didn't work. I already put the whole SDK repository under the working project and change the host name and api key. easyPHP return something like                     
 'Fatal error: Uncaught No CURL support compiled in. Attempted: 1 time(s). thrown in D:\MemberDirectory\infusionsoft-php-sdk\Infusionsoft\App.php on line 192'

Comment: That error would mean that you need to install cURL on your system. I'm not a windows user but [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181082/how-do-i-install-curl-on-windows) may help you get that part solved.

Comment: another question, how can I fetch the company field information by company name?