# "message": "cURL error 60: SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'api-.pusher.com'

Tags: laravel, ssl, curl, chat, pusher

We are implementing a custom chat in a web application using Laravel and pusher. The basic functionalities like sending and receiving messages with file-sharing were working perfectly fine for few days but all of a sudden we encountered an error as follows:

> "message": "cURL error 60: SSL: no alternative certificate subject
> name matches target host name 'api-.pusher.com' (see
> https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for
> [https://api-.pusher.com/apps//events?auth_key=&auth_timestamp=1622911129&auth_version=1.0&body_md5=994999b61168dbbbb9172e79341131b8&auth_signature=51992f8acbe3f6943163bb358399f30b7d8020d30a5d121e1650953480642397"](https://api-.pusher.com/apps//events?auth_key=&auth_timestamp=1622911129&auth_version=1.0&body_md5=994999b61168dbbbb9172e79341131b8&auth_signature=51992f8acbe3f6943163bb358399f30b7d8020d30a5d121e1650953480642397%22),
> "exception": "GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException",
> "file": "/home/techfin/public_html/testtest.com/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php",
> "line": 211

It works perfectly fine on the local machine but causes problems on the server.

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Hi Nico, got the solution added the curl extension and the chat is working. Thanx

Comment: I already installed CURL and everything was working and all of a sudden it stopped working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should install the CURL extension as below (**on Linux**):

```
sudo apt-get install php-curl
```

This will install a dependency package, which depends on the default PHP version. After that restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**on windows:**
[read this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181082/how-do-i-install-curl-on-windows)

**Note:**
Also, your api URL is wrong! instead of `api-.com` use `api-id.pusher.com`

Comment: I am not sure about this answer as I have already installed the CURL with version 7.81 but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the cluster ID from the curl. Normally you'd have an API URL like `https://api-mt1.pusher.com`. You can find the cluster for your app in the Pusher dashboard.